# iOS: can I share urls from Safari to my own app?

Tags: ios, safari, share

I would like to know if it is possible to share a url from the Safari app (or other apps) to my own app? The app I have developed allows the user to store or open a selection of urls.

I know this is possible for Android, but can I also add this to iOS?

**EDIT:**
I want to open my own app to share the page I am currently visiting in the browser. If you press the button to share I would like to be able to select my app, such as in Android: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this will be your solution:

First, you have to register your URL scheme in your `info.plist` file. You want to add the following settings:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>scheme</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.companyidentifier.appname.scheme</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then you have to implement this delegate method to your AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    // handle url here
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: and with this code my app should show up in the share options in Safari?

Comment: if([me isRight]) { return YES; }

Comment: else if ([you !isRight]) { return FALSE; }. This only allows you to open the url from the browser by entering a defined url sheme. What I am looking for, is a way to actually access my app from the share menu in Safari. Such as in Android: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: I would also like to know if this is possible.  I want to have my app show up in the share menu in Safari.  So if you are on a web page and you select the share button, I want my app icon to show up there.  I also know this is possible on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037060/3033056

Starting from iOS 8 you can achieve that by making a Share Extension app. This is a link to a tutorial [ios8-share-extension-swift](http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/) can help and you have to take a look at this link for sharing data between original app and app extension [sharing-code-between-original-ios-app-and-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797242/sharing-code-between-original-ios-app-and-app-extension)