# Sharing code between original iOS App and App Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension, ios8-extension

Sharing class between iOS app and extension app

I want to use a custom class in both my app and the extension app. If I just have the class in the main app folder, the extension doesn't pick up on it. I tried making a copy of it and putting it into the extension folder, but I of course get a `invalid redeclaration of [my class]` error. What's the best solution for this? It's just one class, not multiple resources.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Nothing should be copied. Just add required files to compile sources for your extension:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This looks great! How does this compare to creating a Framework?

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. Creating a framework will not build your class for each target separately. but will do it once and link to each target.

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. In no way. You will just share the code between app and extension. They will be compiled separately. So for example you can use #ifdef SOME_EXTENSION_FLAG ... #endif to disable some parts of code during compilation for App or for extension.

Comment: The downside between this solution and a framework is that effectively the compiled class will be in both the `app` and the `appex` extension, thus increasing the overall size of the IPA file since there is duplication. With a dynamic framework you won't be able to support iOS7 but if you are building a product against iOS8 only, it is a better approach since both the app and the extension will communicate with the same framework.

Comment: It seems to be that if I include ClassA.m in Compile Sources and ClassA has dependencies to ClassB and ClassC, I need to include ClassB.m and ClassC.m as well. This can go pretty crazy, if ClassB and ClassC in return has dependencies and so on. Anyone who has a solution to this problem or who can tell me if I'm missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to create a separate Pre-Compile Header file for the extension if you use one in your app.

Comment: Thank You for explainations. Really Helpful :)

Answer (score 30):

Just make sure that the files you want to share gets a tick in the section **Target Membership**.

Select your file, open the utility panel on the right and tick the appropriate target under **Target Membership**.

[image]

Comment: Just for giving a bit more insight, doing it in this way also adds the class automatically to `Compile Sources` under `Build Phases`.

Comment: that's what I was missing, its really simple.

Comment: Yeah but it is more straight forward in comparison to adding to CompileSources

Answer (score 6):

Embedded frameworks are a great way to reuse code between your application and your extension. Having moved some of the code to embedded frameworks will provide us with a great opportunity to write some unit tests around it.

See section *Using an Embedded Framework to Share Code*
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

Answer (score 3):

**App Extension(e.g Widget aka Today, Photo Editing...)**

- `Containing App` - app which contains an extension or super app
- `Host App` - app which calls `App Extension` and starts extension's lifecycle

For example systems Photos app can be `Host App` for Photo `Editing Extension` like Photoshop Extension which is a part of Photoshop App(`Containing App`)

`App Extension` - available from iOS v8 - it is a `packaged bundle` which uses different process than `Containing App` and can communicate with `Containing App` through App Groups and with `Host App` through IPC. It has `.appex` file extension and is located in `PlugIns` folder. Something similar to CXTests[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65278474/4770877)

Application packaged bundle

[image]

SpeedWidgetExtension.appex - Application Extension packaged bundle

[image]

Communication of `App Extension` and `Containing App`

- Share data - use `App Group`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66457382/4770877)
- Share code

  - `Target Membership` - the simplest way or for pre iOS v8 which allows you to add files into every target. It increases a footprint of package because this file will be duplicated for every target
  - `Framework` - module for grouping/reusing code

    - `Embedded framework` aka `Dynamic framework` - the **most appropriate** way to share common code base. Please turn on `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66510113/4770877) for the framework.  Please note that for using `Embedded framework` you should embed it only in `Containing App` (and **don't** add this framework in `App Extension`. If you include this framework additionally to `App Extension` it will have the same framework inside `App Extension` bundle(additionally to `Containing App`) - framework will be duplicated). It is possible to use single framework for both `Containing App` and `App Extension` because of `@prath`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216681/4770877)

    ```
    //App Extension
    LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = @executable_path/../../Frameworks
    //It means that App Extension can uses Dynamic framework from Containing app
    ```

    - `Static Framework` - link the code to executable binary. You can link library only for `Containing App`

Limitations:

- Widget Extension UI should be written on pure SwiftUI
- Widget Extension not easy to debug on a real device
- Widget Extension is updated when it is possible(not exactly when you specify it)

[[iOS Extension Widget(Today) gray background]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77468566/4770877)
[[iOS extensions]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66554074/4770877)
[[iOS App Group]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66457382/4770877)
[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)