# Checking "Allow app extension API only" in iOS framework project exposes internal classes and methods to consumers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks, ios-extensions

I created a simple iOS framework Swift project and added a single Swift class `Logger` with a single stub method `log(_:)`

```
class Logger: NSObject {

    func log(_ message:String) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `Logger` class and `log` method are internal to the framework, and building normally does not expose them to `ObjC`. If I check the "Allow app extension API only" in the General settings of my framework target, though, the generated `MyFramework-Swift.h` now contains both the class and method declaration, meaning that both are visible to consumers of the framework as if they were declared public:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9Framework6Logger")
@interface Logger : NSObject
- (void)log:(NSString * _Nonnull)message;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Can someone please explain why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't use screenshots to post code snippets.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you enable "Allow app extension API only" the generated header will contain both public and internal classes.

I believe that this is probably a bug in Xcode as this setting should only affect warnings emitted from your compilation (if you reference non-extension APIs) and not affect the contents of the generated `Module-Swift.h`

I am filing a bug report right now.

Comment: I came across this problem using Xcode 12.5. I also checked out your sample project from RadarSample repo and effectively the problem still occurs (the generated headers differ). The problem is that my project build fails since, when flagging "Allow app extension API only" it cannot find a module which gets imported in the wrongly generated header for Swift. Do you know any workaround for avoiding this?

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode Allow app extension API only**

When you check `Allow app extension API only` on a framework target(now it is not presented on General tab) it force a compiler to check if the framework doesn't call any [prohibited system API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6) (Forbidden API `NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE` )

```
//warning
linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions
```

All targets has this reflection in `Build Settings`. It is `Yes` by default for `app extension` targets

```
Require Only App-Extension-Safe API APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY
```