# How to share a class between app and it extension?

Tags: ios, swift, class, imessage-extension

I'm creating a message extension for my app.
To share data between my targets, I use App Group.

In my main app, I have a class IAPHelper, to manage in-app purchases.
Now I need to use this class in my message extension WITHOUT creating the class again.

How can I do?

Comment: You can achieve it by adding your app extension target to your IAPHelper class.

Comment: make sure the desired classes are part of your _extension_'s target as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797242/sharing-code-between-original-ios-app-and-app-extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the class and in your Xcode Utilities you can select your Target Membership:

[image]