# Same extensions in many targets

Tags: swift, module

Im working on a large app, and I have divided it into separate `targets`. I also have a few `extensions`, that are used in many of these targets. I'm wondering if it's better to create separate `target` for this shared `extensions` and then import it in every `module` that uses it, or maybe have these `extensions files` added to all targets that will use them by selecting few targets under "Target Membership"? The second option would actually be more convienient to me, but I'm wondering if this would not make all this extensions be compiled few times - for every target selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best would be to have all this extension in one place like a target or an external library and to import it where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the extensions multiple targets or alternatively add them to compile sources like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28797373/8162321). Of course it would be compiled multiple times then, but that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you creating custom private pod for this goal, including your extensions. Afterwards, you just need to pod install your pod for the other targets.