# iOS - How to differentiate UI and Unit tests, and how to use them in this concrete situation?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am completely beginner about UI and unit tests, and very confused about how to use them, as well as how to differentiate them. So I have thought about the following use case:

I have a user who has a set of `MyData`, a simple object like this:

```
class MyData: NSObject {
    var settled: Bool?
    var id: String?
}

class User {
    var datas: Set<MyData>?
}
```

Here is the behaviour of the application: the user comes on a `MyDataListViewController` that's in a `loading` state first, the `viewDidLoad` method fires an asynchronous function, let's say we use `Parse` for this:

```
static func loadDatas(success: ((Set<Data>) -> Void)?, error: ((String) -> Void)?) {
    // Here we fetch the datas and return then in the success or an error
    // ... 
}
```

The callback result fills the controller's `UITableView`, and when tapping a cell, it opens a modal popup for the specific `MyData` with a button to change its `settled` value.

```
myData.settled = !myData.settled
myData.save()
```

Given this information,

- How would I separate my UI and unit tests?
- How and what should I setup for each of these tests?

Thanks for reading me and helping me out, and sorry again if this sounds very beginner. I'm still very confused about the subject. Also, sorry if a better place than SO matches for this kind of question, I really didn't know where to ask.

Comment: What is it that needs testing?

Comment: Actually I'd like to test almost everything: the behaviour of the views and the modal view, that the objects get actually fetched and then updated and saved...

Comment: Then you ideas of what testing tests are too vague and broad, and that could be the source of some of your difficulty. Testing requires that you separate what's built-in (Apple's code does not need testing, and mostly cannot tested) from what you are doing, and that you separate out the testable "things" into individual units. I'm going to vote to close this question as too broad, and I suggest you watch any or all of the half-dozen or so WWDC videos on this very topic (testing), as they address these matters far better than any single answer here could do.

Comment: I will do so. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your specific questions would be far too long to put in an SO answer. However, one of your root questions seems to be what is the difference between a unit test and a UI test. That *can* be answered here.

The really short version is that unit tests have access to the code in your app (or whatever kind of module you are building) and UI tests do *not* have access to the code.

A unit test only tests one single class per test. Any objects that the class would need to interact with should be replaced with a fake object that the test controls. If you don't insert fake objects you have no way of knowing if a failed test is from the thing you were really trying test or something that it uses. (It should be noted that there is also such a thing as integration tests that test features without faking anything more than maybe network responses).

Ideally for unit tests you want to have a test case class for each class in your app. Then each test case can focus on a single class and test it as throughly as possible.

UI Tests make use of the accessibility features of Apple's various platforms to effectively pretend to be a user using the app. The idea is you use Xcode to record the series of actions to accomplish a task within your app (perhaps to add a todo item) and then edit the code Xcode generates for you to test for specific things, like does the table view now have one todo item in it and does that cell contain the right title.

You will need to use Xcode's recording feature for UI Tests to start with as the code will look a bit foreign to you at first. This is because the UI Tests don't have access to the app's code so it can't ask for an outlet, it has to find the element with accessibility (your life will be way easier if you add accessibility labels to as many of your UI elements as possible).

To get a more in depth look at Unit and UI Testing with Xcode there are a few blog posts and books around:

Blog posts

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/709-ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial
- https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/a-complete-list-of-articles-on-unit-testing-with-swift-from-2017-9be8f046ef25

Books

- https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/test-driven-ios-development-swift-4-third-edition (available on Safari online if you have an account)
- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/store/testing-swift (preorders only at the moment)

I'm sure there are other resources out there but these should get you started. The Ray Wenderlich article should get you a good overview and allow you to formulate more targeted questions for Google and SO.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer. I am going to have a look at these links.

Answer (score 0):

For UI testing user can directly go through simulator with different device version and OS. so that they can get certain UI for each of device and version. As now UI is same important as functionality.

For Unit testing need to involve with the code and for that need to check response of API, set of code, any straight forward crash, flow of application by proper response of relevant APIs. Generally, Developers take care of Unit testing so that application ready for testing.

Answer (score 0):

**Unit vs UI test**

[[Test types]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259827/4770877)

Each of them can implement performance testing. The main advantage of UI tests are a possibility of accessing to UI elements

**App. Unit test** and corresponding MyAppTests.xctest. As you see Unit test is added as a separate module inside `Plugins` folder. The same approach is used for `App Extension`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66520509/4770877)

[image]
[image]

**App. UI test** with MyAppUITests-Runner and MyAppUITests.xctest

[image]
[image]

**Framework. Unit test.**

Can not be run on real device

```
Cannot test target “<target_name>” on “<device_name>”: Logic Testing Unavailable Logic Testing on iOS devices is not supported. You can run logic tests on the Simulator.
```

build folder

[image]

**Framework. UI test** with MyFrameworkUITests-Runner

[image]