# Xcode - check the type of extension

Tags: xcode, ios-app-extension

In iOS there are several app extensions described [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/) and I would like to know how to distinguish each type.

In my current project I have a lot of extensions without a descriptive name. How could i figure out what type of extension is each one of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally I figure out that I can check the type of extension in the Info.plist of each extension.

For example, these identifiers belongs to Notification Service Extension and Notification Content Extension respectively.

```
NSExtension -> NSExtensionPointIdentifier = com.apple.usernotifications.service 
NSExtension -> NSExtensionPointIdentifier = com.apple.usernotifications.content-extension
```

Answer (score 1):

`Info.plist` -> [NSExtensionPointIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionpointidentifier)

```
Action -> com.apple.ui-services
com.apple.services
Custom Keyboard -> com.apple.keyboard-service
File Provider -> com.apple.fileprovider-nonui
File Provider UI -> com.apple.fileprovider-actionsui
(MacOS)Finder Sync -> com.apple.FinderSync
Message Filter -> com.apple.identitylookup.message-filter
Photo Editing -> com.apple.photo-editing
Share -> com.apple.share-services
Call Directory -> com.apple.callkit.call-directory
Account Authentication -> com.apple.authentication-services-account-authentication-modification-ui
Audio Unit -> com.apple.AudioUnit-UI
Authentication Service -> com.apple.AppSSO.idp-extension
AutoFill Credential Provider -> com.apple.authentication-services-credential-provider-ui
Broadcast Setup UI -> com.apple.broadcast-services-setupui
Broadcast Upload -> com.apple.broadcast-services-upload
ClassKit Context Provider -> com.apple.classkit.context-provider
Content Blocker -> com.apple.Safari.content-blocker
iMessage, Sticker Pack -> com.apple.message-payload-provider
Intents -> com.apple.intents-service
Intents UI -> com.apple.intents-ui-service
Network Extension -> com.apple.networkextension.app-proxy
Notification Content -> com.apple.usernotifications.content-extension

//Notification Service - iOS v10 and XCode v8 - allows you to download some content(image, audio, video) ad show it in notification banner(3D Touch). You have 30 seconds to download and save a content. UNNotificationServiceExtension
Notification Service -> com.apple.usernotifications.service

Persistent Token, (MacOS) Smart Card Token -> com.apple.ctk-tokens
(MacOS)Photo Project -> com.apple.photo-project
Quick Look Preview -> com.apple.quicklook.preview
(MacOS)Safari -> com.apple.Safari.extension
Spotlight Index -> com.apple.spotlight.index
Thumbnail -> com.apple.quicklook.thumbnail
(tvOS)TV Top Shelf -> com.apple.tv-top-shelf
Unwanted Communication -> com.apple.identitylookup.classification-ui
Widget(Today) -> com.apple.widgetkit-extension
(MacOS)Xcode Source Editor -> com.apple.dt.Xcode.extension.source-editor
```

[[App Extension(Widget aka Today)]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66520509/4770877)