# How to call function from one target to another target ios swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, siri

In my app, I have two targets.

1. Target 1 -> Main App
2. Target 2 -> Siri Intent Extention.

I have a function in my Target 1 (Main app) which I want to call from Target 2 (Intent Extention)

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between sharing code with any extension and a Siri Intent extension.

You should just add the files you need to the extension target like in this solution [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556508/5209040)

I've done the same with a Share extension.