# App Widgets are greyed out on home screen only

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widget

I am making an app using storyboards and adding Widgets to it later.
I get greyed out widgets on home screen.

[image: greyed out widgets]

It looks fine when opening in widgets drawer.
[image: fine widgets]

Here is my widget UI code

```
ZStack {
        Image(affirmationBGImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        HStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 5)
            HStack {
                Text(affirmationText)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(5)
            Spacer(minLength: 5)
        }
        .padding(0)
    }
```

Also this is my timeline class code

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), affirmationDetails: AffirmationWidgetDetails.random(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), affirmationDetails: AffirmationWidgetDetails.random(), configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        
        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date().zeroSeconds
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 60 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate!)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, affirmationDetails: AffirmationWidgetDetails.random(), configuration: configuration)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let affirmationDetails: AffirmationWidgetDetails
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}

struct AffirmationWidgetEntryView: View {
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        AffirmationWidgetView(affirmationDetails: entry.affirmationDetails)
    }
    
}

@main
struct AffirmationWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "AffirmationWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(
            kind: kind,
            intent: ConfigurationIntent.self,
            provider: Provider()
        ) { entry in
            AffirmationWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Random Affirmation")
        .description("Displays a widget with an affirmation")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemLarge, .systemMedium, .systemSmall])
    }
}

struct AffirmationWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AffirmationWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), affirmationDetails: AffirmationWidgetDetails.random(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I fix this issue so that it appears correctly on home screen just as it shows on Widget drawer?

**NOTE** It works fine on simulator but not on devices for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowed memory to a widget is limited and I reduced the size of image files that I was using and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS Extension Widget(Today) gray background**

Widget has a various of limitations and if you run into one of them you see a gray background

For example:

- Big image size, additionally you find next log

> [archiving] Widget archival failed due to image being too large [2] - (2317, 929).

- Long time execution. If you process image for example it can take a long time, as a result - grey background

[[App Extension(e.g Widget aka Today, Photo Editing...)]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66520509/4770877)